# Transform json into table rows using sql

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, open-json

My initial table looks like this (values of object are dynamic so it's not always the same structure):

```
id  tags 
1   {"tag1": "value1"} 
2   {"tagA": "valueA", "tagB": "valueB"}
```

And I want to transform it into this:

```
id tag   value 
1  tag1  value1 
2  tagA  valueA 
2  tagB  valueB
```

Could anyone help me with the transformation? I tried using OPENJSON like this but it only works if I filter by id (plus I'm not getting the id column in the result):

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET  @json  =  (SELECT tags from auxTagsResources where instanceId = 1)
SELECT \[key\] as tagName, value as tagValue FROM OPENJSON(@json);
```

Result:

```
tagName tagValue
tag1    value1
```

Comment: I've added the sql-server tag to your question because it was pretty clear from the code, but in the future please don't forget to tag your rdbms unless you're looking for an rdbms-agnostic solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply to the json.

> ```
> create table auxTagsResources (
>  id int identity primary key, 
>  instanceId int not null,
>  tags nvarchar(max)
> );
>
> insert into auxTagsResources (instanceId, tags) values
>   (1, N'{"tag1": "value1"}') 
> , (1, N'{"tagA": "valueA", "tagB": "valueB"}');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT tag.id, j.[key] as tag, j.[value] 
> FROM auxTagsResources tag
> CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(tag.tags) j
> WHERE tag.instanceId = 1
> ```

| id | tag | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | tag1 | value1 |
| 2 | tagA | valueA |
| 2 | tagB | valueB |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5d23452c0632d30bd5128496733bb236)*